# URL /%20/ throws configuration file error with external connectionStrings or appSettings files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-10

Had some pen testers test an ASP.NET MVC4 site, and they found I was showing a "raw" error with the URL: /%20/ e.g. https://example.com/%20/

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The configSource file 'Web_ConnectionStrings.config' is also used in a parent, this is not allowed. 

Source Error: 


Line 17:    <!-- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -->
Line 18:    <!-- these settings can be found in external files - this prevents application restart when they are changed -->
Line 19:    <connectionStrings configSource="Web_ConnectionStrings.config" />
Line 20:    <appSettings configSource="Web_AppSettings.config" />
Line 21:    <!-- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -->
```

Although it should be, this isn't a normal 404 error, I already catch those and display a custom page. I also catch 500's and display them nicely too. This error happens earlier than the **Application_Error()** in **global.asax.cs** so it's not caught there.

This seems to be caused by the slash-space-slash confusing IIS or the application, and it's trying to load the web.config's include files more than once or something.

If I include those sections the normal way (not external files - just normal XML sections in the web.config) then everything works as expected and the custom 404 page shows.

If you removed the %20 and just do two slashes, everything works fine. It seems like it has to be this specific URL.

I've seen other posts about IIS configuration with Default Site or virtual paths pointing to the same file location. But I don't think that applies, as I have the Default Site stopped, and I don't see any problems on any other URLs - the site seems to be working fine.

Does anyone know what IIS is trying to do with a /%20/ URL? Or how to handle this more gracefully?

I like having these config sections split out so changes don't recycle the app pool, but if this is a problem with doing this (why are external files allowed then?) then I guess I'll bring all the settings into the web.config itself.